# Котлин корутины, есть ли что-то по красивее чем withContext(Dispatchers.Main)?

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть код в android приложении:

```
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val res = // что-то очень сложное...
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            // Взаимодействие с view 
        }
    }
```

Я недавно работаю на котлине, и мне интересно есть ли в данном конкретном случае более простое и удобное решение чем withContext? А то из-за него иногда выходит слишком много отступов.
P.S. Если есть какие-нибудь хорошие и подробные статьи по котлину, поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: А чем withContext неудобный? ps. [The reason to avoid GlobalScope](https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc#:~:text=Structured%20concurrency%20in%20Kotlin%20Coroutines,do%20not%20recommend%20using%20GlobalScope%20.)

Comment: Слишком много табуляций выходит. Идёт нормальный код, потом идёт запуск корутины и + табуляция ко всему последующему коду, затем идёт withContext + ещё одна табуляция, затем идёт, например if, + ещё одна табуляция. Есть парочка мест, где у меня это доходит до бредовых 5 табуляций, и приходится выкидывать совсем небольшой код в отдельные функции. Для меня важна читабельность кода

Comment: Насчёт боязни GlobalScope, я вообще не так уж и много знаю о котлинских корутинах.

Comment: можете выносить в отдельные функции `suspend fun updateUI(param: SomeParam) = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { /* */
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Диспетчер по-умолчанию можно определить в контексте корутины, для этого нужно реализовать интерфейс `CoroutineScope` в вашей активити, презентере или viewmodel (в зависимости от вашего архитектурного подхода).

Для примера, как это можно сделать в активити:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        launch {
            println("Current thread is ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
    }
}
```

GlobalScope при этом использовать не нужно.

Comment: Да, почитал хороших статей по карутинам, узнал про CoroutineScope, GlobalScope и lifecycleScope (Последний и использую). Тем не менее ваш ответ для меня новость, не думал что так можно. Спасибо!